# Error in keras in getting class labels in imagedata test generator for creating confusion Matix

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create confusion matrix for an Image segmentation.  My image data consists of MRI Image of Left Atria, Ground truth or mask image of binary segmentation of Left Atria.

I have created the following code for test and train data generators

```
SEED = 999
BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN = 16
BATCH_SIZE_TEST = 16

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200
IMAGE_WIDTH = 200
IMG_SIZE = (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)

NUM_TRAIN = 1320
NUM_TEST = 440

NUM_OF_EPOCHS = 75
```

```
data_dir_train = 'data/Train/'
data_dir_train_image = os.path.join(data_dir_train, 'img')
# The images should be stored under: "data/Train/img/img"
data_dir_train_mask = os.path.join(data_dir_train, 'mask')
# The images should be stored under: "data/Train/mask/img"

data_dir_test = 'data/Test/'
data_dir_test_image = os.path.join(data_dir_test, 'img')
# The images should be stored under: "data/Test/img/img"
data_dir_test_mask = os.path.join(data_dir_test, 'mask')
# The images should be stored under: "data/Test/mask/img"
```

```
def create_segmentation_generator_train(img_path, msk_path, BATCH_SIZE):
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1./255,
                         featurewise_center=False,
                         featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                         rotation_range=0,
                         width_shift_range=0.0,
                         height_shift_range=0.0,
                         zoom_range=0.0
                         )
    
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    datagen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)      
    
    img_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED,shuffle=False)
    msk_generator = datagen1.flow_from_directory(msk_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED,shuffle=False)
    return zip(img_generator, msk_generator)


def create_segmentation_generator_test(img_path, msk_path, BATCH_SIZE):
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1./255,
                         featurewise_center=False,
                         featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                         rotation_range=0,
                         width_shift_range=0.0,
                         height_shift_range=0.0,
                         zoom_range=0.0
                        )
    
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    datagen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
        
    img_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED,shuffle=False)
    msk_generator = datagen1.flow_from_directory(msk_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED,shuffle=False)
    return zip(img_generator, msk_generator)
```

```
train_generator = create_segmentation_generator_train(data_dir_train_image,data_dir_train_mask,BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN)
test_generator  = create_segmentation_generator_test(data_dir_test_image,data_dir_test_mask, BATCH_SIZE_TEST)
```

Now when I try to get classes from test_generator

```
true_classes = test_generator.classes
```

I get following error as

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 true_classes = test_generator.classes

AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'classes'

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a specific code modification for Zip object since I have created image and mask generators as zip objects?  Please help.

Comment: I did a small work around as per github article and modified the code to `return(pair in pair zip(img_generator, msk_generator))`.  I am  getting the error as AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'classes'.  I did a `dir(test_generator)` and found "__class__".  I tried creating `true_classes = test_generator.__class__` and I get output as generator object but not getting class labels.  What am I doing wrong?